# How to change which port WSL2 uses?

Tags: windows-10, networking, port, wsl2

I'm using `Acrylic DNS` and it somehow conflicts the `port` with what `WSL2` uses and I cannot open `WSL2`.

---

When I kill the `Acrylic DNS` I can now open `WSL2`:

```
netstat -a -n -o
// outputs: UDP    [::]:53                *:*                                    3968

taskkill /f /pid 3968
// kills Acrylic DNS
```

---

But i don't want to do I that since I want to keep using `Acrylic DNS` on port `53`.

So how can I change which port `WSL2` uses on windows10?

Comment: Do you have a service called SharedAccess enabled and running?

Comment: I don't think I have...